# Org-wide Addresses after split

Tags: split

What will happen with the Organization-wide Addresses after org split? Will they remain active, or become `not verified` or something else?

I've been searching for the answer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-prepare-for-a-Split) but with no success.